# Filtro no WHERE Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, filtro, where

Bom dia pessoal, seguinte, estou fazendo uma padronização de alguns registros aqui na empresa. Portanto existem 2 tabelas.

Tabela A(registros antigos) colunas como:

```
id_alvara | logradouro
1         | Rua Sete de Setembro n° 200
2         | Rua tal 300
3         | Rua de Teste n555
4         | Rua nada 2000
```

Tabela B(registros novos) colunas como:

```
id_logradouro | logradouro | num
1             | Rua Tal    | 220
2             | Rua de Test| 555
```

O que pega é o seguinte, como eu faço um filtro na tabela A para pesquisar pelo numero exato?

Por exemplo, em um formulário, o usuário está digitando o numero 220, tem que retornar para ele o registro 1 correto?

Eu usei no WHERE um like( ... where like '%200%') mas isso me retorna qualquer número que tenha 200, e isso não me resolve.

Como filtro e tiro todas as letras?

Acho que deu para entender, aguardo retorno e agradeço e quem responder! Abraço

---

EDIT1: Dando destaque ao problema, às vezes, o usuário, quando cadastrou seu endereço, colocou o número de sua residencia assim: n°220 ou n220 etc, isso impede que eu use diretamente o 220.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Tu tá pesquisando na tabela A, eu vou lá e escrevo: 200, tu não quer usar o like pq vai retornar todos os logradouros que tiverem 200 em alguma posição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema utilizando uma função translate.

Vou colar o SQL aqui para quem interessar:

> `SELECT a.id_alvara, a.id_alvara as numero, a.nome, a.firma, 
>        a.tipo_log||' '||a.logradouro||' '||a.complemento as endereco
>           FROM alvara a JOIN atividade at ON a.id_atividade = at.id_atividade
>       WHERE (translate(a.tipo_log||' '||a.logradouro||' '||a.complemento, translate(a.tipo_log||' '||a.logradouro||' '||a.complemento, '1234567890', '') , '')) = '220'`

Answer (score -1):

O codigo que voce tem com 'WHERE LIKE "%220%" procura todos os elementos que tem 220 no meio, isso daria conflitos eventualmente pois poderia retomar varios registos com 220 inseridos no meio e não apenas o 220, portanto este deverá de funcionar
    "SELECT * FROM num WHERE num = 220"
ou
    "SELECT * FROM num WHERE num LIKE "220""

Comment: O problema é com o SELECT na primeira tabela.. na segunda eu consigo de boa.

Comment: Deculpe, parece que percebi mal a pergunta, experimente então "SELECT * FROM tabelaA WHERE logradouro LIKE "%220"", isso pesquisara todos os registos que tenham o numero 220 no fim

Comment: Eu já havia tentado, isso ameniza mas não resolve!

Comment: SELECT substring(logradouro FROM '[0-9]+') FROM tabelaA este aqui é uma outra maneira de extrair numeros de uma frase

Comment: Consegui de outro modo, mas valeu pela resposta (Y)